# Магический метод, &

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как в данном случае перезаписать применение оператора `&` в Python через магический метод `__iand__`?

```
def __iand__(self, others):
    self & others = search_general(self, others.id)
```

Comment: Что такое search_general?

Comment: В магических методах & это `__and__`, а то что вы пишите `__iand__` это &=

Comment: search_general в данном случае это метод класса

Answer (score 2):

если вы ходите чтобы при `a&b` вернулось `search_general(a, b.id)` то так:

```
def __and__(self, others):
    return search_general(self, others.id)
```

если `search_general` это метод класса то так:

```
def __and__(self, others):
    return self.search_general(others.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявляете метод `__and__` реализуете как вам будет угодно реакция на &. И возвращаете результат через `return ...`

```
class A(object):
  def __and__(self, other):
      return 'New format: {} & {}'.format(self, other)

a = A()
a2 = A()

print(a & a2)
>>> New format: <__main__.A object at 0x7f16fe8b3970> & <__main__.A object at 0x7f16fe8ab4f0>
```